# how reslove responsive image in custom module to Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-9

I upgrade the drupal7 to drupal9
how i can make the responsive image in custom module
$banner_img['large_image'] = $base_url.'/'.$module_path . '/images/flower-02.jpg';
$banner_img['mid_desktop_image'] = $base_url.'/'.$module_path . '/images/flower-02.jpg';
$banner_img['ipad_image'] = $base_url.'/'.$module_path . '/images/flower-02730.jpg';
$banner_img['mobile_image'] = $base_url.'/'.$module_path . '/images/flower-02560.jpg';
please help

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 9, responsive images are handled differently.
You need both responsive images and breakpoint modules.

Please see this as a guide: https://www.prometsource.com/blog/how-set-responsive-images-drupal-9-0

Comment: I upgrade the drupal 7 to drupal 9 these module the banner_img is in info file in drupal 7 how can i custom way  in module include the banner_img in drupal 9.